# Can i pass a function returned data to jquery on() event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

here is my code

```
var addproduct = {
    init:function(){
        var footer = $("<div class='footer'></div>");
        var confirmButton = $("<button class='dbtn'>confirm</button>").on('click',this.confirm);
        var cancelButton = $("<button class='dbtn'>cancel</button>").on('click',this.cancel);
        d.append(footer.append(confirmButton,cancelButton));

        $('body').append(d)
    },

    getData:function(){
        var data={};
        d.find('#basic_info :input').each(function(){
            data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
        });
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    },

    confirm:function(e){

        console.log(e.data);
    },

    cancel:function(){
        alert(2);
    }

}
```

when i click the confirm button i want to submit the form in 'd',so i want to use 'getData' function to get all the form data,

here is what i did

```
var confirmButton = $("<button class='dbtn'>confirm</button>").on('click',this.getData,this.confirm);

//output: function()
```

so i guess the data pass to the handler can not be a function right???

and then i change the confirm function like this

```
confirm:function(){

     var data = this.getData()
     console.log(data);
    },

 this will not work too , because the 'this' keyword is not the addproduct object,but the confirm button '<button>confirm</button>';
```

so how can i pass the getData function's return data to confirm function?????

and why the 'this' isn't the addproduct object ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var confirmButton = $("<button class='dbtn'>confirm</button>")
                     .on('click',this.getData(),this.confirm);
```

`getData` returns the data object you want to pass to the event handler so you have to actually call the function. Then you should be able to see the data here

```
confirm:function(e){

    console.log(e.data);
},
```

Comment: by the way why is 'this' keyword is not the addproduct object but the button

Comment: @chenliang from http://api.jquery.com/on/ `When jQuery calls a handler, the this keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events this is an element matching selector. (Note that this may not be equal to event.target if the event has bubbled from a descendant element.) To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be used with jQuery methods, use $(this).`

Comment: what if i want to call another method of addproduct object in confirm?

Comment: i try this confirm:function(e,this){

     
     console.log(this);
    },  it wont work ,dose it mean i can only pass one arguments to a handler

Comment: @chenliang try `.on('click',[this.getData(), this],this.confirm);`